# Data truncated for column 'SubordinateID' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I have a table Employees and a table Manages. In my table Manages I have ManagerID and SubordinateID who form together a primary key. ManagerID en SubordinateID are both a foreign key referring to EmployeeID. How can I write a code to implement alle the Employee ID's that a manager manages.

For example Manager 1 with employee ID 1 manages Employees with EmployeeID 2, 4, 5 and 13.
I tried to do this as follows

```
INSERT INTO `Manages` (`ManagerID`, `SubordinateID`) VALUES ('1', '2,4,5,13');
INSERT INTO `Manages` (`ManagerID`, `SubordinateID`) VALUES ('2', '6,10,5');
INSERT INTO `Manages` (`ManagerID`, `SubordinateID`) VALUES ('4', '10,5,7');
INSERT INTO `Manages` (`ManagerID`, `SubordinateID`) VALUES ('3', '7,8,9');
INSERT INTO `Manages` (`ManagerID`, `SubordinateID`) VALUES ('11', '12');
```

What's wrong? I got following error:

```
ERROR 1265: 1265: Data truncated for column 'SubordinateID' at row 1
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `group22`.`Manages` (`ManagerID`, `SubordinateID`) VALUES ('1', '2,4,5,13')
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items! It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: But how should I store it properly?

Comment: One row per ManagerID/SubordinateID combination. I.e. (1,2), (1,4), (1,5), (1,13)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because comma is a special character in sql and I expect you can escape it. But the best way is to change your relation between Employees en Managers. Here I describe some situations depending on what you need:

**I) OneToMany**

If your employees are managed by one manager only you could create a `OneToMany` relation. So each employees will have a `manager_id` field wich is the foreign key related to the manager.

**II) Recursive OneToMany**

If you doesn't have any Managers table, Employees refer to itself

**III) ManyToMany**

If your employees can be managed by 1 or more managers, you should implement a `ManyToMany` relation. You need a third table, and in it you need to store every combination of manager / employee using 2 foreigns keys ( one for the managers and one for the employees ).

**IV) Recursive ManyToMany**

If you only have an Employees table, just create two foreign key fields wich refer to the same table. After all managers are employees too.

Answer (score 0):

`Manages` seems like a table that has one row per manager and subordinate.

You need to insert each row separately.  So, instead of:

```
INSERT INTO `Manages` (`ManagerID`, `SubordinateID`)
    VALUES ('1', '2,4,5,13');
```

You would use:

```
INSERT INTO `Manages` (`ManagerID`, `SubordinateID`)
    VALUES (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 13);
```

Also, do not use single quotes for number constants.  They indicate that value is a string.